# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory Azure Python error

Tags: python, azure

I'm attempting to make the callout as per this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/form-recognizer/quickstarts/python-receipts?tabs=v2-0

And I'm defining the source as this:

```
source = r"https://ocrstoragebeta.blob.core.windows.net/files1/download_token=0991878f8063e-1e5e-4859-`enter code here`9505-2d2fd6f097f945969-00P4J000000qXMlUAM (1).png"
```

And keep seeing the following error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'https://ocrstoragebeta.blob.core.windows.net/files1/download_token=0991878f8063e-1e5e-4859-9505-2d2fd6f097f945969-00P4J000000qXMlUAM (1).png'
```

I'm hosting the file in a blob storage. What's going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you can only use local path like the document descriped:

> Replace `<path to your receipt>` with the path to your local form document.

If you want use the file stored in azure file share, you should connect it to your local computer first and make sure the path is correct.
[image]

Comment: Please Accept as Answer if my answer helps you, this can be beneficial to others. @Barnik Bhattacharyya

Answer (score 0):

Form Recognizer can accept a URL as the input document.

Discard this answer if you plan on using the REST API, but I wanted to point out that there is an SDK [here](https://pypi.org/project/azure-ai-formrecognizer/) and a [sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/sdk/formrecognizer/azure-ai-formrecognizer/samples/sample_recognize_receipts_from_url.py) that demonstrates how to analyze a receipt using a URL.